# Is the concept of vector bundle is a special case of the notion of family of algebraic varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, schemes, moduli-space

If we start from the definition of the notion of families of varieties ( or algebraic ( projective ) varieties more precisely ), as proposed by Joe Harris in his book: Algebraic geometry: A first course, page: $41$ : Is the concept of vector bundle, ( i.e: locally free sheaf ), or projective vector bundle is a special case of the notion of family of varieties ( or algebraic ( projective ) varieties ) ?

If so, why then the concept of tensor product between two vector bundles is replaced by the notion of fiber product over a base in the case of : families of varieties ( or algebraic varieties more precisely ) ? In other words, does a the notion of fiber product over a base coincide locally with the notion of tensor product ? How can we express this mathematically ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you remind us of the definition of a family of varieties? A vector bundle is certainly a family of affine spaces over a variety in some sense

Comment: Fiber product of two vector bundles over a scheme $S$ is the direct sum of the vector bundles and not tensor product.

Comment: @leibnewtz : For any variety $B$, a family of projective varieties in $ \mathbb{P}^n $ with base $ B $ is simply a closed variety $ \mathcal{V} $ of the product $ B \times \mathbb{P}^n $. The fibers $ V_b = \pi^{-1} (b) $ of $ \mathcal{V} $ over points $ b \in B $ are then reffered to as elements of the family $ \mathcal{V} $.

Comment: @leibnewtz : The idea is that if $ B \subset \mathbb{P}^m $ is projective, the family $ \mathcal{V} \subset \mathbb{P}^m \times \mathbb{P}^n $ will be described by a collection of polynomials $ F_i ( Z,W) $ bihomogeneous in the coordinates $Z$ on $ \mathbb{P}^m $ and $W$ of $ \mathbb{P}^m $, which we may then think of as a collection of polynomials in $ W $ whose coefficients are polynomials in $ B $.

Comment: @Mohan : If fiber product of two vector bundles over a scheme $S$ is the direct sum of the vector bundles and not tensor product, which object related to families over a scheme $S$ is the tensor product of the vector bundles ? Thank you

Comment: None that I know of in a simple way.

Comment: @Mohan : I think you make a mistake. If you take a look here : http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?3,657899,657942 , $ \oplus $ corresponds to $ \coprod $, and $ \otimes $ corresponds to fiber product $ \times_B $, no ?

Comment: No, fiber product of two vector bundles (even by dimension considerations) can only be direct sum. For example, consider two vector bundles of ranks $m,n$ over the spec of a field. Then the fiber product has dimension $n+m$, not $nm$.

Comment: Thank you Mohan. :-)